# simple procedure take a table name as parameter and show its content

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

```
create procedure showMe @Tname varchar(30)
AS
BEGIN
    select * from @Tname        -->>am i violate some rules !!
END ;
------------------------------------------
```

@JNevill  i think i get your idea but not properly.

```
      create procedure showMe @Tname varchar(30)
      AS
      BEGIN
      declare @SS varchar(40) = 'Select * from '
      declare @CC varchar(80)
        @CC = @SS + @Tname  
        sp_executesql @CC
     END ;
```

i find the solution.......

```
  create procedure showMe @Tname varchar(30)
  AS
  BEGIN
    EXEC('select * from ' + @Tname)
  END ;
```

Comment: You'll need to store the SQL statement in a varchar variable concatenating in the table name to that sql string, then use `EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @YOURSQLSTATEMENT` to execute it. [See examples here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql)

Comment: You can't parameterize identifiers in sql. You can use dynamic sql for this but I would not recommend it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, if you are just selecting * from a table passed to the procedure, why do you need it to be in a procedure? Some context into what you are trying to achieve with this would be helpful.